# How to convert back maven project to java web project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee

I have converted my **java web project** to **maven project** using **m2e plugin** in eclipse. Now i need to convert it back to java web project. So now how it is possible to change it back to java web project.

Comment: A java-web-project may be very complex. A simple translation is not possible. Why shall you do this?

Comment: because now i am seeing bulk of errors in my project.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Please try the following:

1. Open context menu on the maven project
2. Select "Maven" -> "Disable Maven Nature"

Hope that helps.

Comment: Why not? If I add the maven nature to a normal java project and disable it later, it's just the normal java project like before.

Comment: Well, I won't compile in the ./bin folder back. You may have to reconfigure your .classpath and .projects and others files.

Answer (score 2):

Use this maven command

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

http://mytechnologythought.blogspot.com/2017/09/convert-maven-project-to-eclipse.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when attempting to use Maven with EFXclipse. I wanted to revert, but faced all kinds of unknown errors after following the answer from [@DirkNM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26588517/2947478)

So, I just created a new project of my particular type (be it an EFXclipse project, web, java, etc.)

And then re-added all source files and project dependencies to build-path manually.

Sounds harder, but was way easier... considering I didn't have to go looking for all kinds of random settings not reverted back using the answer from @DirkNM