# Eclipse Convert to faceted form recovery

Tags: eclipse

i have configured my project as Convert to Faceted Form on Eclipse. i want to get back now, how can i do it? Also how can i get back all like this?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert back maven project to java web project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26588439/how-to-convert-back-maven-project-to-java-web-project)

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was navigating to `Project -> Properties -> Project Facets` and in the configuration drop-down, I selected 'Default Configuration'.

You can modify the custom configuration to your needs too, of course.